# Support for CloudFormation Custom Resource in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation, terraform

I've scoured the Terraform docs for the AWS provider and couldn't find support for CloudFormation::CustomResource in terraform.

I've created my Lambda Functions and now I would like to pass my arguments to my lambda function. The way this is done in CloudFormation is via a custom resource.

I however can't seem to find support for this in Terraform. Am I missing something? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[The `aws_cloudformation_stack` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudformation_stack.html) allows the creation of CloudFormation stacks in Terraform, thus exposing all of CloudFormation's features within a Terraform configuration:

```
resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "example" {
  name = "example-custom-resource"

  template_body = <<STACK
{
  "Resources" : {
    "ExampleCustomResource": {
      "Type" : "Custom::ExampleResource",
      "Properties" : {
        "ServiceToken": "...",
        (other properties specific to the resource)
      }
    }
  }
}
STACK
}
```

The `Type` attribute here can be any string starting with `Custom::`. The `ServiceToken` identifies which custom resource provider will handle this custom resource. Any other properties that the custom resource supports can be provided as additional attributes in the `Properties` object.

Since the format of `template_body` is just a standard CloudFormation template, [the documentation for `CustomResource`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cfn-customresource.html) gives the full details on how this feature works.

Terraform does not *directly* support CloudFormation custom resources as a native Terraform resource, but the `aws_cloudformation_stack` resource is provided as a way to get the best of both worlds, giving access to CloudFormation-specific features when needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following Provider, it works the same like AWS CloudFormation Custom Resources. You can use it with AWS Lambda or run a script locally in any language

https://github.com/mobfox/terraform-provider-multiverse

```
provider "multiverse" {}

resource "multiverse_custom_resource" 
  "spotinst_targetset_and_rules" {
      executor = "python3"
      script = "spotinst_mlb_targetset.py"
      id_key = "id"
      data = <<JSON
 {
    "name": "test-terraform-test",
    "mlb_id": "lb-123",
    "mlb_deployment_id": "dp-123",
    "mlb_listener_ids": ["ls-123", "ls-456"],
    "test_group_callback_fqdn": "test.fqdn.com",
     "control_group_callback_fqdn": "control.fqdn.com"
  }
 JSON
}
```